# Jade locals scoping

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a problem with scoping when using locals in my Jade template. My code is...

```
function(req, res) {
    BlogPostModel.find({}, function(e, data) {
        if (e) throw e;

        posts = data;

        var path = __dirname + "/view/admin/blog.jade",
            template = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8"),
            options = { filename: path },
            fn = jade.compile(template, options),
            html = fn(posts);

        res.end(html);
});
```

The above code renders fine, but I'm having to make 'data' a global variable. I would rather pass 'data' directly into my function call. But when I do that, I get a 'variable is not defined' error from Jade. Can anyone tell my why 'data' is out of scope?

Thanks,

FBZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it wasn't a scoping problem at all. I had to call my argument 'locals'. Like this...

```
BlogPostModel.find({}, function(e, locals) {
    if (e) throw e;
    var path = __dirname + "/view/admin/blog.jade",
        template = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8"),
        options = { filename: path },
        fn = jade.compile(template, options),
        html = fn(locals);

    res.end(html);
});
```

Seems strange that Jade accepts a global variable of any name, but a local variable must be called 'locals'. Anyway, sorted.